# android app that locates people who are offline using android phone

Tags: library

in our country it is hard to be online 24 ours that is why me with my friends are trying to bulid an android app that helps people to know their location and based on that they can do what ever they want

Comment: If they are not online, then the best you can hope for is the last location where they were online. Is that good enough?

Comment: Noble goal, but what is your question? SR is about recommending software that meets specific requirements you define, see [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](https://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/336/185). By the tag used, one could guess you're looking for a library – but what should that library supply?

Answer (score 1):

If someone is not online, then you cannot use their phone to locate them.

There are two reasons not to be online: cost and infrastructure. Since you say "in our country it is hard to be online 24 hours", I guess that your problem is infrastructure; maybe the 'phone network, probably the electricity network.

Without those, of course, there is no way to know for certain where someone is right now.

I can think of two helpful things, both based on habit. While your fends ***could*** be anywhere, there are probably some places where they are 90% of the time (home, school shopping mall, bar, church, club, etc, etc)

If you can't code - start learning (or get one of your friends to do so). Python is a powerful and easy to learn language and can be run on Android. Java is better for Android, but might be harder to learn.

Track your friends. After a few days or weeks, your software will be able to say "at 11a.m, there is an 87.5% chance that Joshua is at ...".  I do not know of any app which can do that. Perhaps @Izzy does?

If you can spare a few $, the US $9 the [Raspberry Pi Zero W](https://www.raspberrypi.org/blog/raspberry-pi-zero-w-joins-family/) has BlueTooth & WiFi. You can put one in each commonly visited location and use it to register when friends walk past and update their last known location when it gets a chance of internet connection.

Even without internet, phones can communicate by BlueTooth, when friends pass each other. An app can store the GPS location, then whenever a phone goes online, it can upload its data to a server, which can store the last know locations.

Am I thinking in the right direction?  Might this help to solve your problem, or did I misunderstand?